# Constant behaves different in webpack production build

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Right now my development build behaves like it should. I render a list of projects and each entry in the lists has project.id as a key. All entries in the list are different as i would expect.

This is the code which works fine.

```js
for (const project of sortedProjects) {
    if (project.id) {
        projects.push(
            <ProjectListItem
                key={project.id}
                project={project}
            />,
        );
    }
}
```

Now i want to cleanup a bit and create a `const projectId = project.id;`.

```js
for (const project of sortedProjects) {
    const projectId = project.id;
    if (projectId) {
        projects.push(
            <ProjectListItem
                key={projectId}
                project={project}
            />,
        );
    }
}
```

The webpack production build is now broke because every project in the list is the same. I think somehow the projectId is the same for every entry. But my tests don't reflect that. When i log (`console.log({ project, id: project.id, projectId });`) the projects and ids everything is unique as it should be.

`const { id } = project;` would work too.

Comment: Are you sure the broken webpack build is due to that particular line? I don't thin it would make any difference at all. What is the error message you got?

Comment: I don't get any error message. Like i wrote the key attribute does not work as expected anymore. It seems like projectId is the exact same value for every project. But only in production. The same code in develop works flawelessly.

Comment: What is the difference between the bundled code for production and for development? Maybe it does something weird when bundling it, the code above also looks fine to me

Comment: Where is the values of projects coming from?

Answer (score 3):

Is `projects` initially an empty array? If so, you could do the following:

```
const projects = sortedProjects
    .filter((project) => project.id)
    .map(
      (project) => <ProjectListItem key={project.id} project={project} />
    );
```

Like others have said, I doubt the issue relates to webpack.
As this is a React related issue, just make sure you haven't done something silly like setting `id` based on a transient value like index within a sorted array. Keys need to be unique identifiers that don't change based on state.